# Hide an applet on javacard

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

As you know, we can see a list of AID of applets reside on a smart card using `gpj -list` or using similar commands in another tools (such as **gpshell**, **gp** , **opensc-tool** ...)

I want to know is there any way to hide an applet to list in the response of these kind of commands? I mean uploading an applet in a way that when we use `gpj -list`, the smart card doesn't return its AID!

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this question?

Comment: Why would you want to hide the applet? This information is only accessible to those who have the card content management keys.

Comment: @lletami I don't want to hide any applet! I have a card, and I have IDS keys and I want to know is there any hidden applet that I can't see! Maybe a back-door!

Comment: There are ways to hide applets so that they do not show up in the GET STATUS response, but these are platform proprietary features.

Comment: @lletami And how I can see if is there any hidden applet or not? Whould you please give me a way to hide an applet? which kind of platforms have this feature? Thanks\

Comment: You wouldn't be able to see them unless you knew the proprietary commands to "activate" them. What I am trying to say is that there are ways to hide apples during card manufacturing, but to actually make them visible requires specific platform knowledge.
Unfortunately I cannot help you try to figure this out, but I am simply trying to make you aware that this feature does in fact exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to list the AIDs of applets, executable load files and security domains, all these tools generate `GET STATUS` APDUs, which first need to establish a secure channel to the ISD.
So if I didn't want the world to know that a specific applet is installed in the card, I would rotate the ISD keys.

If I were even more paranoid, wanting to limit not only applet listing, but also checks for my applet existence, I would make it not selectable.

Comment: Thank you dear mictter. Would you please explain more detailed the first paragraph? What do you mean by **rotate the ISD keys**? How I can do it?
And about the second paragraph : If I hide and applet and make it not selectabl, then I can't do anything with it? (just deleting) right?

Comment: "rotating the ISD keys" is a very widely used expression. It means changing the default keys in the Card Manager, also called the Issuer Security Domain (I am assuming that you are using the default keys). Each tool has different commands to do it, for example GPShell uses `put_sc_key` http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/#key-commands

Comment: You can access a non-selectable applet from other applets (using some JavaCard shared interface you'd have to program) and also perform management operations on it: extradite, make selectable, delete...

Comment: If I change the keys, nobody can list the AIDs!If I want to hide just one AID from the person who has ISD keys! Is this possible?!

Comment: If someone has the ISD keys, I am afraid there is not much you can do... the ISD will return information about all applets installed in the card: AID, status, privileges...